# Python 3 Data Frame string manipulation to extract numbers between 8 to 12 characters

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm not sure where to start with this one.

I have a list of obsolete items with a new item_code listed somewhere in the description column. Item codes are always between 8 & 12 characters so all other numbers in the description should be ignored.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'Item_Code': ['00001234', '00012345', '00123456', '01234567'],
'Desc': ['Widget1 - Obsolete Use Alternative 56789100', 'Obsolete Widget 2 - Use Alternative 
56789100 - Blah Blah Blah', 'Alternative Use 9999999910 - Blah Blah Blah', 'Obsolete use 99999999911']},
index=[0, 1, 3, 4])
print(df1.head(10))
```

[image]

So ideally I'm looking to have the alternative codes in a new column.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) like so:

```py
df["Alternative"] = df["Desc"].str.extract(r"(\d{8,12})")
```

This applies the regex `r"(\d{8,12})"` ([explained here](https://regex101.com/r/Hndt1Z/1)) over each row. The values in the resultant column will be strings unless you convert them to integers.

Comment: This is awesome, but how would I deal with Multiple in the same cell? for example:- 
 "Widget1 - Obsolete Use Alternative 56789100 or  56789101"
Ideally, I'd want a new row for each replacement item if possible

Comment: You would need to use [`Series.str.extractall`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) but this returns a DataFrame with a multi index so needs more work to join the rows back together.